# Business Objects 4: decrease the refresh time

Tags: query-optimization, business-intelligence, business-objects

I have a report with a refresh time of about 1 minute, that I reduced from 5 minutes by doing the following:

- Displaying fewer elements (e.g. tables, charts)
- Making the formulae as simple as possible (e.g. simplifying nested if statements)
- Making the queries simpler (e.g. pulling through fewer columns)

My question is, **are there any other ways for me to reduce refresh time that I haven't considered?**

Comment: Are these reports using universes or SQL queries?

Comment: @Lima: Universes. Due to company policy relating to access, I cannot change the universe itself

Comment: Do you have a target refresh time in mind?  How many records is being pulled down?

Comment: @Lima: I'd like to get the refresh time down to 10 seconds or less if possible. My query pulls 500 employee names, with associated sales data (total sales value, total sold items, average value per item sold and profit). The average employee sells 960 items per month, giving an underlying number of items being 480,000

Comment: Can you take the SQL query that the report is using and run it directly in SQL Management Studio, or whatever DB management tool you use?  Be interesting to see how quick the query is within SQL and see if it is the query or BOE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking round the office shows that the methods I used were optimal from my side. Slow refresh times were caused by systemic under investment by my employer, e.g.

- Universes being clunking and indexed incorrectly
- Slow internet connection/being restricted to IE
- Slow laptop to access BO4

This lead me to build a business case to invest in the infrastructure by leveraging the amount of time lost in waiting for reports to refresh.